# C++ inheritance not inheriting

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

rectangleType.h

```
class rectangleType
{
public:
    void setDimension(double l, double w);
      //Function to set the length and width of the rectangle.
      //Postcondition: length = l; width = w;

    double getLength() const;
      //Function to return the length of the rectangle.
      //Postcondition: The value of length is returned. 

    double getWidth() const;
      //Function to return the width of the rectangle.
      //Postcondition: The value of width is returned. 

    double area() const;
      //Function to return the area of the rectangle.
      //Postcondition: The area of the rectangle is 
      //               calculated and returned.

    double perimeter() const;
      //Function to return the perimeter of the rectangle.
      //Postcondition: The perimeter of the rectangle is 
      //               calculated and returned.

    void print() const;
      //Function to output the length and width of 
      //the rectangle.

    rectangleType();
      //Default constructor
      //Postcondition: length = 0; width = 0;

    rectangleType(double l, double w);
      //Constructor with parameters
      //Postcondition: length = l; width = w;

private:
    double length;
    double width;
};
```

rectangleType.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"rectangleType.h"

using namespace std;

void rectangleType:: setDimension(double l, double w){
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

double rectangleType:: getLength() const{
    return length;
}

double rectangleType:: getWidth() const{
    return width;
}

double rectangleType:: area() const{
    return (length*width);
}

double rectangleType:: perimeter() const{
    return ((length*2)+(width*2));
}

void rectangleType:: print() const{
    cout << "the width is: " << width << endl;
    cout << "the length is: " << length << endl;
}

rectangleType:: rectangleType(){
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
}

rectangleType:: rectangleType(double l, double w){
    length = l;
    width = w;
}
```

boxType.h

```
class boxType : public rectangleType
{
public:
    void setDimension(double l, double w, double h);
      //Function to set the length, width, and height 
      //of the box.
      //Postcondition: length = l; width = w; height = h;

    double getHeight() const;
      //Function to return the height of the box.
      //Postcondition: The value of height is returned. 

    double area() const;
      //Function to return the surface area of the box.
      //Postcondition: The surface area of the box is 
      //                calculated and returned.

    double volume() const;
      //Function to return the volume of the box. 
      //Postcondition: The volume of the box is 
      //               calculated and returned.

    void print() const;
      //Function to output the length, width, and height of a box.

    boxType();
      //Default constructor
      //Postcondition: length = 0; width = 0; height = 0;

    boxType(double l, double w, double h);
      //Constructor with parameters
      //Postcondition: length = l; width = w; height = h;

private:
    double height;
};
```

boxType.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"boxType.h"
#include"rectangleType.h"

using namespace std;

void boxType:: setDimension(double l, double w, double h){
    length = l;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

double boxType:: getHeight() const{
    return height;
}

double boxType:: area() const{
    return (length*width*height);
}

double boxType:: volume() const{
    return ((2*length*width)+(2*length*height)+(2*width*height))
}

void boxType:: print() const{
    cout << "the width is: " << width << endl;
    cout << "the length is: " << length << endl;
    cout << "the height is: " << height << endl;
}

boxType:: boxType() : rectangleType.cpp(){
    height = 0;
}

boxType:: boxType(double l, double w, double h) : rectangleType.cpp(double l, double w){
    height = h;
}
```

RectangleTypeTest.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"rectangleType.h"
#include"boxType.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    rectangleType firstRectangle;
    rectangleType secondRectangle(2, 2);

    firstRectangle.setDimension(3, 3);
    cout << "rectangle's length is: " << firstRectangle.getLength() << endl;
    cout << "rectangle's width is: " << firstRectangle.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "rectangle's area is: " << firstRectangle.area() << endl;
    cout << "rectangle's perimeter is: " << firstRectangle.perimeter() << endl;
    secondRectangle.print();

    boxType firstBox;
    boxType secondBox(2, 2, 2);
    firstBox.setDimension(3, 3, 3);
    cout << "box's length is: " << firstBox.getLength() << endl;
    cout << "box's width is: " << firstBox.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "box's height is: " << firstBox.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << "box's area is: " << firstBox.area() << endl;
    cout << "box's volume is: " << firstBox.volume() << endl;
    secondBox.print();


}
```

I am compiling it with:

```
g++ -o rectangleTest rectangleTypeTest.cpp rectangleType.cpp boxType.cpp
```

I am getting the error messages:

```
In file included from boxType.cpp:2:0:
boxType.h:2:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
boxType.cpp: In member function ‘void boxType::setDimension(double, double, double)’:
boxType.cpp:8:2: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
  length = l;
  ^
boxType.cpp:9:2: error: ‘width’ was not declared in this scope
  width = w;
  ^
boxType.cpp: In member function ‘double boxType::area() const’:
boxType.cpp:18:10: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
  return (length*width*height);
          ^
boxType.cpp:18:17: error: ‘width’ was not declared in this scope
  return (length*width*height);
                 ^
boxType.cpp: In member function ‘double boxType::volume() const’:
boxType.cpp:22:13: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
  return ((2*length*width)+(2*length*height)+(2*width*height))
             ^
boxType.cpp:22:20: error: ‘width’ was not declared in this scope
  return ((2*length*width)+(2*length*height)+(2*width*height))
                    ^
boxType.cpp:23:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
boxType.cpp: In member function ‘void boxType::print() const’:
boxType.cpp:26:30: error: ‘width’ was not declared in this scope
  cout << "the width is: " << width << endl;
                              ^
boxType.cpp:27:31: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
  cout << "the length is: " << length << endl;
                               ^
boxType.cpp: In constructor ‘boxType::boxType()’:
boxType.cpp:31:23: error: type ‘rectangleType’ is not a direct base of ‘boxType’
 boxType:: boxType() : rectangleType(){
                       ^
boxType.cpp: In constructor ‘boxType::boxType(double, double, double)’:
boxType.cpp:35:51: error: type ‘rectangleType’ is not a direct base of ‘boxType’
 boxType:: boxType(double l, double w, double h) : rectangleType(double l, double w){
                                                   ^
boxType.cpp:35:65: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 boxType:: boxType(double l, double w, double h) : rectangleType(double l, double w){
                                                                 ^
boxType.cpp:35:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 boxType:: boxType(double l, double w, double h) : rectangleType(double l, double w){
                                                                       ^
```

The error seems to be mainly not declared in this scope errors. It seems to me like it is not inheriting from rectangleType. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at www.sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors

1. The variables that you want accessible to inherited classes must be protected; *not* private.
2. The functions that you want "polymorphically" called must be virtual; unless you are trying to just create class specific functions that happen to have the same name; in which case if you have a base class pointer, the base class function would be called, regardless of whether the abject pointed to is a box or rectangle.
3. And if this is homework, then this is a bad example to give. A box is NOT a type of rectangle. "is type of" is kind of rule to follow when defining class hierarchies. e.g. what is the area of a box? Kind of non sense.

Comment: The header files were given by my professor so I was under the assumption that they were correct. So, I cannot override a function unless it is virtual?

Comment: You can define a function with the same name as the one in base class. Nothing prevents you. Read what I wrote - it just won't act polymorphically. There is difference. There is a term to explain the difference; the term is not just clicking to me right now.

What was the assignment? Derive a class out of rectangle? I doubt.

Comment: He gave me the two header files and told me to write the class files for them. I have made no changes to the header files. Can you explain what you mean by won't act polymorphically? Do you mean I cannot access the parent class's variables/function?

Comment: I do not have the context; BUT if this is it, i.e. there is not other context, then change the professor. Easier than changing c++ to allow it to do what you are trying to do.